# How to load a particular layout (perspective) on startup in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I have enabled `dotspacemacs-auto-resume-layouts` in `.spacemacs` file. I created a new layout named `acme` and quit spacemacs.
Now when I start spacemacs again, I am presented with the default screen (showing the spacemacs banner and recent projects and files). I have to switch to the layout I want using `SPC l 2`.

Is there a way I can tell spacemacs to load the `acme` layout by default? Or maybe programmatically switch to the layout by adding some function calls in `user-config` part of `.spacemacs`?

Comment: I have also tried adding `(persp-switch 'acme)` to `.spacemacs` but it throws an error

Comment: Where did you add? `dotspacemacs/user-config`?

Comment: @TianshuWang Yes. In the file `.spacemacs`, function `dotspacemacs/user-config`. I got the error "Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Wrong type argument: hash-table-p, nil"

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the following in your `user-config`, Though I don't know why it open `*scratch*` buffer

```lisp
(add-hook 'persp-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (persp-load-state-from-file)
              (persp-switch "@Spacemacs")))
```

Comment: This didn't work @tianshu

Comment: The combination of setting dotspacemacs-auto-resume-layouts to t in dotspacemacs/init and adding the hook you mentioned works great for me.  Thank you!